# How to call a method which inherited from parent class with Ajax in MVC.NET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

In my appliaction i have a controler Message

```
public class MessageController : BaseController
{
   ...
}
```

The BaseController is a abstact class and contains a method FindUserForMessages. This Method must be in this controller, because this "BaseController" is used like a parent in 3 similiar web application and includes a common functionality of all application.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult FindUser(string userName, int maxRecords)
    {
        try
        {
            return Json(new JsonResult()
                {
                    IsError = false,
                    ErrorMessage = string.Empty,
                    Data = (from u in AccountModel.FindUser(userName, false).Take(maxRecords)
                            select new
                            {
                                UserName = u.UserName,
                                UserId = u.ProviderUserKey,
                                IsOnlien = u.IsOnline
                            })
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this method to a source of JqueryUI AutoComplete widget. I am trying to call this method by Ajax:

```
$("#txtQuickMessageSendTo").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Message/FindUser",
            data: {
                userName: request.term,
                maxRecords: 10
            },
            success: function (resultObj) {
                if (resultObj.IsError) {
                    handleAjaxError(null, null, null, null, resultObj.ErrorMessage, null);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    response($.map(data.Data, function (item) {
                        return { 
                            label: item.UserName,
                            value: item.ProviderUserKey
                        }
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        //log(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.label : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
    },
    close: function () {
        $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
    }
});
```

I use a Fiddler2 for Web Debugging and in request are both parametrs(userName and maxRecords), but server throw an error:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Message/FindUserForMessages
```

parameters are Ok, but why i cannot call this method?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Your error message says you were trying to access `FindUserForMessages` method. But the method in your code is `FindUser` !

**2)** Also, always use Html helper method to get the path to the action methods. So replace

```
url: "/Message/FindUser",
```

with

```
url: "@Url.Action("FindUser","Message")",
```

**3)** By default, ajax action type is `GET`. Your action method is decorated with `[HttpPost]` atttribute. So either remove that from there or mention that when you make the ajax call. Also make sureyou really need the `Authorize` attribute for your requirement.

```
public JsonResult FindUser(string userName, int maxRecords)
{
  return Json( new { YourJsonDemo="replace here" }, 
                                                  JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Or do it in the client side to say it is a `POST` request.

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "@Url.Action("FindUser","Message")",
          type: 'POST',
         //remaining code
```

Answer (score 0):

FindUser method accepts only post. Either remove the [HttpPost] attribute (you will need to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet - unrecommended), or make sure the jquery ajax options specifies type = post.